# new wordpress tag does not show

Tags: wordpress, tags, portfolio

I added a new **tag** to my Portfolio section. On the portfolio page there is a section that shows certain **tags**. Here is the code that is pulling the **tags**.

```
<?php

$tags = explode(',', $woo_options['woo_portfolio_tags']); // Tags to be shown
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    $tag = trim($tag); 
    $displaytag = $tag;
    $tag = str_replace (" ", "-", $tag);    
    $tag = str_replace ("/", "-", $tag);
    $tag = strtolower ( $tag );
    $link_tags[] = '<a href="#" rel="'.$tag.'">'.$displaytag.'</a>'; 
}
$new_tags = implode(' ', $link_tags);

?>
```

I have validated that `$woo_options['woo_portfolio_tags']` returns a comma seperated string of the **tags** that get displayed. I have no idea where this is being set. I have tried search in all the files.

Also in `theme-options.php` i see the following code but not sure where the actual values are being set.

```
$options[] = array( "name" => "Portfolio Tags",
                "desc" => "Enter comma seperated tags for portfolio sorting (e.g. web, print, icons). You must add these tags to the portfolio items you want to sort.",
"id" => $shortname."_portfolio_tags",
"std" => "",
"type" => "text");
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by:

1. Going to the Theme settings from the Wordpress left menu
2. In the Theme setting there was section for Portfolio
3. In the Portfolio section add the new tag.